# Qt Timer Problem

Tags: c++, qt4, timer

I have a timer whose tick time is 100. but it tick 125 msec.So i   reduced the tick time from 100 to 80, but i still tick approximately 125 msec again. This timer is in main thread. How can i solve  this  problem? and i m open any suggestions.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: All non-realtime OS give no guarantee on sleep time. This is what underlying OS provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.2/qtimer.html

> .... a timer cannot fire while your
>   application is busy doing something
>   else. In other words: the accuracy of
>   timers depends on the granularity of
>   your application.

and

> Note that QTimer's accuracy depends
>   on the underlying operating system and
>   hardware. ...  If Qt is unable to
>   deliver the requested number of timer
>   clicks, it will silently discard some.

NOTE: Some older version of Qt use other api that give 20-50ms accuracy.

All non-realtime OS give no guarantee on sleep time and it depends on your cpu power and how bust your system is, you should never relay on this.